# Django multi-db bulk_create

Tags: postgresql, django-models

Django documentation on [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) specifies a way to specify database connection run time with `obj.save(using='not_default')`. But if I have multiple objects to save, I would prefer using bulk_create to improve performance.

Is there a way to achieve multi-db write with `MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_model_list)`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [bulk_create source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fb8fd535c0f47cffb4da0c5900f3f66e1ec8d432/django/db/models/query.py#L420) I saw that it uses the db connection from the model manager.

So the answer to my question is:
`MyModel.objects.using('not_default').bulk_create(my_model_list)`

I'm using postgres so the call also updates the primary keys in `my_model_list`. So if one is going to call it twice for different connections remember to set them to `None`.